# "Страна" и "странный", есть ли связь?

Tags: однокоренные-слова

Существует ли связь между словами «странный» и «страна»? 
Примечание: странный, в смысле – необычный, страна – государство.
На мой взгляд, есть, так как «странный» походит на «сторонний», «посторонний» - с другой стороны, с другой «страны». Возможно, я не прав.

Answer (score 4):

Связь непосредственная. Слово "странный" образовано от слово "страна", имевшего в старославянском языке значение "чужая страна", а чужой- это всегда непонятный, необычный. Так и поменялось постепенно значение.

Answer (score 3):

Стоит человек, а от него в разные стороны простираются дороги. Какой простор! Слово "сторона" пришло в наш язык из глубины веков: и.-е. корень ster - расширять, распространять, о.-с. основа - storna.

В др.-рус. языке слово "сторона" существует с 11 века -  это бок, земля, край. Со стороны брёл  "стороньникъ"  (страньникъ - по-книжному). С 14-15 веков появляется слово "стороньный" в значении "посторонний, чужой", а "сторониться" чужаков начали только со второй половины 18 века. А уж потом: "Господи, что за город! . Постой, посторонись, задавят, несут что-то!" (Ф. Достоевский).

В книжной речи слово "странный" заимствовано из ст.-сл. языка ка производное с суффиксом ьн от "страна" в значении "чужая страна". Странный - это "чужестранный, чужой", а потом - "необыкновенный, непонятный".

Таким образом, получается, что слово "странный" со страной/государством  не связано, первоначальное значение - чужой, сторонний.